# Merging two patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I have the following test file:

```
words

words

aa

   word132 b word1 word2 ...
  word131 c word1 word2 word3 word4 ...

bb

words

words

aa

   word132 bi word1 word2 ...
  word131 ci word1 word2 word3 word4 ...

bb
```

I want to find between aa and bb words in every second column. So desired result is:

```
b
c
bi
ci
```

I've managed to do it this way:

```
<?php


$pattern = '

words

words

aa

   word132 b word1 word2 ...
  word131 c word1 word2 word3 word4 ...

bb

words

words

aa

   word132 bi word1 word2 ...
  word131 ci word1 word2 word3 word4 ...

bb

';


$result = array();

preg_match_all('/aa\s*(.*)\s*bb/isU',$pattern,$matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    preg_match_all('/(?:\s*)(?:\w+) (\w+) (?:.*)/i',$match, $submatches);    
    foreach ($submatches[1] as $submatch) {
        echo $submatch."<br />";
    }    
}
```

But I would like if possible (and make sense) create one search pattern from those 2 ones I used. How can it be done if for each of them I use other modifiers?

I don't have great experience with regular expressions so is it reasonable to merge those 2 patterns or for more complex actions you should rather run regex on result of previous regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** You can use this single regex:

```
if ( preg_match_all(
    '~(?>\baa\b|\G(?<!^))\s*\K^ *\S+ +(\S+).*?$(?=(?:(?!\baa\b).)*?\bbb\b)~sm', $str, $m) )
   print_r($m[1]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
    [2] => bi
    [3] => ci
)
```

#### * [Online regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dR6sZ7/1)

**Earlier Solution:**

You can use `preg_replace_callback` to solve this problem in 2 phases:

```
$arr = array();
preg_replace_callback('~\baa\n(.*?)\nbb\b~s', function ($m) use (&$arr) {
    if (preg_match_all('~^ *\S+ *(\S+)~m', $m[1], $w)) $arr = array_merge($arr, $w[1]); },
    $str);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: That's nice one but is there any chance to do it using one PCRE pattern? If no, how you can guess that something cannot be done using one pattern?

Comment: Reason why I believe 2 phase approach is better because PCRE doesn't support variable length lookbehind like `.NET`. You can wait for more answers to see if anybody can post a single regex to solve this. I am all for keeping things simple and readable though.

Comment: ok check edited code now for a single PCRE regex to solve this problem.

Comment: Atomic, `\G` and `\K` in the same "simple" pattern!... +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81 I wanted to keep it simple that's why posted `preg_replace_callback` solution earlier. However OP wanted single CRE regex so had to come up with that. If you have some suggestion to simplify it further feel free to comment.

Comment: No, it's beautiful, I love it. In the same spirit, this short one also works: `(?m)^aa(\s*\S* +\K\S+)|\G[^\r\n]*\R+^(?!bb)(?1)` or with possessive `(?m)^aa(\s*+\S*+ ++\K\S++)|\G[^\r\n]*+\R++^(?!bb)(?1)`

Comment: Thanks so much @zx81, I know a bit about recursive sub patterns but need to learn about them properly it seems.

Comment: @anubhava You seem to be doing great with `(?R)` in nested constructions. :) Actually this one is really easy, it's not really recursive, just a subroutine: `(?1)` simply means "match again the pattern from Group 1" so we don't have to paste `\s*\S* +\K\S+` in the regex again—cleaner. `(?(DEFINE)...)` is another option of course but IMO overkill in this case.

Comment: Thanks for these great tips @zx81 I am learning new things every day on SO